# repath renderlayer output

Tags: python, scripting

I'm using blender 2.79 and I want to change the render layer output path of a scene.

I have a lot of scenes to render and the output path for the beauty can be controlled via command line. I wrote a batch script, this script set an environment variable for the path, where the render layer has to be stored.

Inside the blender file everything is set, but not the render layer path.

How can I change the path?

I used this script, but if I run it, it creates a new fileoutput.001 and 002. I only want to change the existing one though.

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
nodes = scene.node_tree.nodes

render_layers = nodes['Render Layers']
output_file = nodes.new("CompositorNodeOutputFile")
output_file.base_path = "//my/folder/"
```

Also, I import the environment variable using:

```
slicepath = str(os.environ.get("basepath")
```

And I get:

```
S:\Clients\Blender279\scene1a\
```

But I think blender wants:

```
S:\\Clients\\Blender279\\scene1a\\
```

Kind regards, thunderbolt

Comment: hi, i got it to work, i wrote a new script from scratch